# How to set default group for files created in Samba share

Tags: windows, samba

I'm sharing a directory, `/home/pi/pydev` on a debian box (raspberry pi, in fact) with Samba. I'm reading from and writing to that directory from a Windows 7 machine. 
When I create, under W7, a file in that directory, it gets 0764 rights, and it's owned by user rolf and group rolf - that's me on the W7 machine.

User pi on the debian box and user rolf (on W7) both need to be able to modify files in that directory, so I made them both member of group `coders`, hoping I could configure it so that members of coders have at least read & write access to files in that directory. .

But user pi can't modify any file that belongs to group rolf.

I could `chmod rolf:coders <filename>` file by file.
Adding user pi to group rolf is ugly, and doesn't work (didn't expect that. Does Samba maintain an entirely different user administration with groups, beside Debian's?).
I could also log on to the debian machine as rolf, and navigate to that folder.

But the most elegant way (to me) would be if a file created by rolf from the W7 machine would get userid rolf and groupid coders, by default.

Can I configure Samba to do that, or is there some other way to automate that task?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking correctly then what you want is inside the `smb.conf` located here:

```
   /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Add these options to the `[global]` section:

```
   force user = rolf
   force group = coders
```

Comment: In case like me someone is looking to add user, group, and actual permissions string add `create mask = 0775`

Comment: you do know that the `force` directives make *any* user do operations as the specified user/group? say e.g. you have a share `/joe` and a share `/anne`, if you do `force user = anne` on share `/anne`, then user `joe` can access `/anne`, big no-no and a big security risk! this option is so misleading it should be documented better and not used lightly

Answer (score 10):

you could try adding sticky bit for the group on that folder

```
chmod 2770 foldername
find foldername -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
```

Comment: Like it. The right answer should be this one. Making group permissions on directories and subdirectories sticky is a typical Linux filesystem problem and not a Samba problem.

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: The description of the two kinds of "sticky bits" does not go along with what the answer suggests. Or is it that "execution" of a folder is like execution of a file and therefore the folder then "runs" with ownership under the group that was specified? That is the only way I could imagine how it works.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79395/how-does-the-sticky-bit-work

Comment: @bomben that Q&A focuses on executables; see [this discussion of permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183999/86440) for details of setgid’s effect on directories.

Answer (score 1):

On a samba domain with `samba-tool`:

```bash
samba-tool group addmembers 'My Group Name' 'My Username'
samba-tool user setprimarygroup 'My Group Name' 'My Username'
```