# How to set the permission drwxr-xr-x to other folders?

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

I have few directores inside a folder like below -

```
teckapp@machineA:/opt/keeper$ ls -ltrh
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 10 teckapp cloudmgr 4.0K Feb  9 10:22 keeper-3.4.6
drwxr-xr-x  3 teckapp cloudmgr   4.0K Feb 12 01:44 data
```

I have some other folder as well in some other machines for which I need to change the permission to the above one like this `drwxr-xr-x`.

Meaning how can I change any folder permissions to `drwxr-xr-x`? I know I need to use `chmod` command with this but what should be the value with chown that I should use for this?

Comment: Please consider reading this link - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm

Comment: This is trivial: `man chmod`.

Comment: a better source after the man page would be http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x9543.htm

Comment: Take a lok at [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/what-does-a-d-stand-for-in-unix-file-permissions)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To apply those permissions to a directory:

`chmod 755 directory_name`

To apply to all directories inside the current directory:

`chmod 755 */`

If you want to modify all directories and subdirectories, you'll need to combine *find* with *chmod*:

`find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +`

Comment: If you want to inlcude subdirectories, use: `chmod -R 755 */`

Answer (score 11):

For drwxr-xr-x it is:

```
chmod 755  the_path_to_target
```

For drwxrwxr-x it is:

```
chmod 775  the_path_to_target
```

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to @aguslr (I do not have enough reputation to comment):

`chmod` as well as `chown` has a `-R` flag, that changes all rights recursively