# What file mode is a symlink?

Tags: symlink

What file mode indicates that a file is a symbolic link (symlink)?

---

My use case is to detect symbolic links inside a git repository (and its history). I was under the impression that a symlink is a symlink because of its file mode, and that file mode is what the tool `chmod` sets.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/303040/how-do-file-permissions-apply-to-symlinks

Comment: It seems my question may have better been asked 'what file mode are symlinks in git'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465436/git-how-to-handle-symlinks

Comment: `chmod` sets permission bits (rwx and sticky/setuid/setgid bits, ...) : this is what we call a "mode". But you seem to be referring to file **types** instead.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith I would be eager to upvote a link to documents distinguishing the differences of file modes and files types! :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

File modes cover two different notions: file types and file permissions. A file's mode is represented by the value of `st_mode` in the result of `stat(2)` calls, and `ls -l` presents them all together; see [Understanding UNIX permissions and file types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-their-attributes) for details.

Once a file is created its type can't be changed. In addition, on Linux systems you can't specify a symlink's permissions; all that matters is the target's permission (and effectively the full mode since that determines the symlink's behaviour too). See [How do file permissions apply to symlinks?](https://superuser.com/q/303040/414739) for details. On Mac OS X symlinks can have their own permissions.

Finally, `git` uses a simplified model, with a limited number of recognised modes:

- `040000` for a directory
- `100644` for a normal file
- `100755` for an executable file
- `120000` for a symbolic link

You can see these values using commands such as `git cat-file -p 'master^{tree}'`; see [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) for details.

Answer (score 2):

> What file mode indicates that a file is a symbolic link (symlink)?

The POSIX API to check if a file is a symlink is using the `S_ISLNK` macro.

In glibc, `S_ISLNK` is defined as follows:

```
#define __S_IFMT    0170000 /* These bits determine file type.  */
#define __S_IFLNK   0120000 /* Symbolic link.  */
#define __S_ISTYPE(mode, mask)  (((mode) & __S_IFMT) == (mask))
#define S_ISLNK(mode)    __S_ISTYPE((mode), __S_IFLNK)
```

i.e. a file is a symlink `if ((mode & 0170000) == 0120000)` (at least on GNU/Linux).

Answer (score -1):

A symlink (though some filesystems handle symlinks differently) is an `inode` table entry that points to the same place as another file (or directory).

For example if `foo` is `inode 1234` then `bar` (a symlink to foo) is `inode 1234`.

`bar` doesn't really exist it's just a pointer to a "real" file.

`Symlinks` generally don't have permissions outside the permissions of the file they point to. So `bar's` permissions are "the same" `as foo's`. You can't set permissions on `bar` (the symlink) only on `foo` (the real file).

That being said, it's a really high level view. Different file systems handle symlinks differently. Different tools handle `symlinks` differently. Some file systems "flag" `symlinks` and handle them specially, but some don't.

For example `chmod` on `Linux` won't change a `symlinks` permissions but on `OSX` you can get it to. In both cases the real files permissions are changed.

I can not think of any system (doesn't mean it's not out there) where a `symlink` has permissions separate from the real file.

Comment: No, a symlink is a type of file ("everything is a file") that contains a filename rather than general-purpose data.  Typically this filename refers to an existing file — that's the whole point of having symlinks — but this is not guaranteed to be true.  Yes, a symlink (like every other type of file) has an inode.  No, a symlink and the file it points to have separate inodes, with different inode numbers.  ***Hard*** links have the same inode, and thus the same inode number.

Comment: well it was meant to be high level but modern systems don't make a file on the hard drive the inode table contains the string and no real file is created. I think it's called "fast symlink"

Comment: If 'foo' and 'bar' are both pointers to node 1234, then they're HARD links, not symlinks. If "bar" were a SYMlink, then it would literally be the character string "foo" (or even the path to foo) instead of an node. In fact, you can create a symlink that doesn't point anywhere meaningful at all, e.g. `ln -s 'this is not a real file' bar`

Comment: Also: BSD (which includes Mac OS X) has an lchmod() system call which will let you set the permissions of the symlink itself. I have no idea what the use of that is.