# File permissions categories

Tags: files, permissions

So I am a little bit confused with File permissions categories. So here is what I do understand and correct me if I am mistaken.

For every File , there is an Owner (one user) which have a symbol u and for every file there maybe a group of users who own the file (most of the times the owner = group ?)
a group can have access to it Including the owner himself as a member of that group.

And others refer to all the people who are not in the group and not the owner right ?

So when dealing with permission the user is the owner ?

and all (a) refers to the owner (u) + group (g) + others ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a POSIX filesystem, every file has a user (the file's owner), a group, and permissions for the user, the group, and everyone else.

For every user, access to a given file is determined as follows:

- if the user is the file's owner, the owner permissions apply;
- if the user is a member of the file's group, the group permissions apply;
- in all other cases, the other permissions apply.

The order here is significant; thus you can have a file which is owned by you, with permissions `0077` (everything for the group and others, nothing for the owner), and you will not have access to it! But since you're the owner you can change that with `chmod`. This can be useful in some cases where you want to deny access to a specific group and allow anyone else access (think of a `students` group in an academic context).

Strictly speaking permissions aren't matched to the end user, but to a process's effective user, which may be different (*e.g.* for set-uid binaries). There can also be other factors affecting groups, *e.g.* on NFS mounts.

Permissions can be set with `chmod` (see [Understanding UNIX permissions and their attributes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-their-attributes/183999#183999) for details), and one option is to use the letter you mention: `u` for the user permissions, `g` for the group permissions, and `o` for other permissions. Using `a` with `chmod` applies the permissions to all three categories.

In modern systems other access permissions can apply on top of or instead of these permissions; look up ACLs (`setfacl`), SELinux etc.