# '+' and 's' in permission strings

Tags: permissions, ls, authorization

If the ls -l command gives me a permission string like

```
rwsr-s--x
```

What does the 's' mean? The only sources I found mention that it can be present sometimes but do not elaborate.

What does a '+' instead of a '-' mean? I have found mentions of 'extended permission' but nothing clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As explained by the very good and comprehensive wikipedia page on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Symbolic_notation) :

> `+` (plus) suffix indicates an access control list that can grant additional permissions. Details are available with `man getfacl`.

Furthermore, there are three permission triads :

> - **First triad** : what the owner can do
> - **Second triad** : what the group members can do
> - **Third triad** : what other users can do

As for the characters of the triad :

> - **First character**
>
>   - **r** : readable
> - **Second character**
>
>   - **w** : writable
> - **Third character**
>
>   - **x**: executable
>   - **s** or **t**: executable and
>       setuid/setgid/sticky
>   - **S** or **T**: setuid/setgid or sticky, but not
>       executable

The [setuid/setgid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) basically means that, if you have the permission to run the program, you will run it as if you were the owning user and/or of the owning group of that program. This is helpful when you need to run a program which needs root access but also needs to work for non-root users (to change your password, for example).

The [sticky bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) might have different meaning depending on the system or flavor you are running and how old it is, but on `linux`, [the wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) states that :

> [...] the Linux kernel ignores the sticky bit on files. [...] When the sticky bit is set on a directory, files in that directory may only be unlinked or renamed by root or the directory owner or the file owner.

Comment: `getfacl` is a program that has never been standardized. It exists only in a standard proposal from around 1993 tat has been withdrawn in 1997.

Answer (score 4):

See [Understanding UNIX permissions and their attributes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-their-attributes/183999#183999) for an explanation of the `s`.

`+` appears after the standard permissions, and is one of the possible characters used to indicate that the file has "alternate access methods". With GNU `ls` the character can be blank (the default), `.` to indicate a security context applies to the file, or `+` to indicate any other alternate access method, typically ACLs (which you can see using `getfacl`).

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) defines the position as being used for the alternate access method flag, but possible values are left to each implementation:

> The *optional alternate access method flag* shall be the empty string if there is no alternate or additional access control method associated with the file; otherwise, it shall be a string containing a single printable character that is not a *blank*.