# Permission errors even though permissions are wide open

Tags: permissions, ls, selinux

I installed anaconda on our new VM and I can't list its contents. I can change my directory to .../anaconda/ but when I type `ls -l` I get:

```
ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied
```

However, when I enter:

```
sudo ls -l
```

I get

```
total 92
drwxrwxrwx.   2 gcw8 PosixUsers 12288 May 26 15:30 bin
drwxrwxrwx.   2 gcw8 PosixUsers 12288 May 26 15:30 conda-meta
drwxrwxrwx.   3 gcw8 PosixUsers  4096 Mar 27 16:33 docs
drwxrwxrwx.   2 gcw8 PosixUsers  4096 Mar 27 16:33 envs
drwxrwxrwx.   2 gcw8 PosixUsers  4096 Mar 27 16:33 etc
drwxrwxrwx.   6 gcw8 PosixUsers  4096 May 26 15:19 Examples
drwxrwxrwx.  41 gcw8 PosixUsers  4096 May 26 15:19 include
drwxrwxrwx.  11 gcw8 PosixUsers 20480 May 26 15:19 lib
-rw-rwxrwx.   1 gcw8 PosixUsers  3700 Nov  7  2013 LICENSE.txt
drwxrwxrwx. 185 gcw8 PosixUsers 12288 May 26 15:30 pkgs
drwxrwxrwx.   3 gcw8 PosixUsers  4096 Mar 27 16:33 plugins
drwxrwxrwx.  10 gcw8 PosixUsers  4096 Mar 27 16:33 share
drwxrwxrwx.   3 gcw8 PosixUsers  4096 Mar 27 16:48 ssl
```

The `groups` command indicates that I'm a member of PosixUsers and I'm the one who initially created this so why can't I access it? At one point I ran `chmod -R ugo+rwx .../anaconda/` but I still don't see how that would result in this error. If anything, it should alleviate it. I'm running CentOS and all of this is being done via ssh. Can anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note the `.` at the end of the permissions (`drwxrwxrwx.`): that means there's an SELinux context involved. You need to get that right for your user to be able to list the contents of the directory.

To see the contexts for your directory, run

```
sudo ls -alZ
```

(the `-Z` option shows the SELinux contexts required).

The [CentOS wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) has a good page on SELinux. You'll find more information about the last character in the permissions at ['+' and 's' in permission strings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206909/and-s-in-permission-strings/206912#206912).

Comment: @son_of_fire: Stephen is right, `+` is for any other combination of access restrictions, `.` is reserved for SELinux only. IMO would belong into the answer, though.