# Setting the SUID for the user at the beginning

Tags: permissions

I want to add suid. The folder has this permission `drwxrwxrwx` and I want to change it to `srwxrwxrwx`. Everything I have tried and read about replaces it at the end of the groups. How can I make it so it appears in the beginning of the user group?

```
deploy@dimsum:/tmp$ ls -l
total 752
srwxrwxrwx 1 deploy deploy      0 Dec 16 09:18 puma-status-1450232293388-7085
srwxrwxrwx 1 deploy deploy      0 Jan  8 16:58 puma-status-1452247111766-14349
```

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). What do you actually want to do?

Comment: @terdon: Well the actual problem is not related to Unix.

Comment: Um, then why are you asking here? What makes you think that `srwxrwxrwx` is what you need? That's not actually possible anyway, the first letter will always be a `d` for a directory. You can get `drwsrwsrwx` if you like, but what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @terdon: Adding that folder gave me another error message, suggesting that it recognized the directory exists, but that it doesn't have permission to write to it. Adding my output

Comment: Also explain where you "added" it and what complained. Your output shows sockets, not directories. And you don't need SUID to have access to anything. Please explain what you are trying to do and not the solution you are trying to apply. The solution could be (almost certainly is, based on what you say) wrong. We can't help unless you tell us what the final objective here is.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-their-attributes/183999#183999 to understand why you can't change the first character.

Comment: If you create a socket and assign it mode 777, then you will see `srwxrwxrwx`, please note that `s` as first character means "socket" and not "suid".

Comment: @dave_alcarin: Ah ok, that explains it then. And answers my question. Post it as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: @dan-klasson I don't understand why you refuse to explain what your aim is. We might actually be able to help.

Comment: @terdon: It's specifically related to a Ruby app being deployed with Capistrano. And the error is specifically with Puma.

Comment: @dan-klasson as you wish. Just note that making these sockets is probably not what you need to do and that, if you actually show the specific error message you are getting, we might be able to offer a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments, this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101), but:

- Please note that the first letter `s` means "socket" and not "SUID"
- If you create a socket and assign it the mode 777, you will see exactly `srwxrwxrwx`
- Also mentioned in the comments, a very good post regarding information about the first letter, permissions, and attributes is to be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-their-attributes/183999#183999)

Note that this might not solve **your original problem**!