# What are the final 3 bits in the UNIX permission mode bits?

Tags: files, permissions, filesystems, inode

I understand there are 12 permission bits of which there are 3 groups of 3 bits for each of user, group, and others, which are RWX respectively. RW are read and write, but for X is `search` for directories and `execute` for files.

Here is what I don't get:

1. What are the 3 remaining mode bits and are they all stored in the inode?
2. I know the file directory itself is considered a file as well, since all things in UNIX are files (is this true?), but since UNIX systems use ACL to represent the file system, then the file system is a list of filename-inode_number pairs. Where does a file directory store it's own inode number and filename?

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183999/86440) should cover the first part of your first question.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. As a matter of fact I have read the answer before but I'm a little dense at this so I didn't get a clue about the last 3 bits.. The closest thing I can infer from that answer is 3 bits can represent 0 to 7, and there are 4 values that can set permissions apparently (like 0777), and each number in each position represent some permission?

Comment: The 0 (first digit) in your example (0777) references the suid, sgid and "sticky" bit per Stephen's link. The first 7 (second digit) is the 3 bits (RWX) of the owner's permissions. The second 7 (third digit) is the 3 bits of the group's permissions. The final 7 (fourth digit) is the 3 bits of the others' permissions. You're correct in understanding that 3 bits together can represent a number from 0 to 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`stat /bin/su` shows on one system:

```
Access: (4755/-rwsr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

There's the octal representation `4755` of all 12 mode bits. The number corresponds to the bits:

```
octal    4   7   5   5
bits   100 111 101 101
       sst uuu ggg ooo
       ug  rwx rwx rwx
```

Where `uuu`, `ggg` and `ooo` are the permission bits for the user, group and others. The remaining group (the first one in order) contains the setuid (`su`), setgid (`sg`) and sticky (`t`) bits.

The setuid and sticky bits are often not mentioned, since they're zero for most files. They're still there for every file, saved along with the others.

---

If we really get down to it, some filesystems and interfaces store the file *type* along the mode bits, in the still-higher bits. The above only accounts for 12 bits, so with a 16-bit field, there's 4 left over. See, for example, the [description of `st_mode` in `stat(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html).

Answer (score 3):

1. The remaining three bits represent the setuid, setgid and sticky bits; see [Understanding UNIX permissions and file types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183994/86440) for details. These are all stored in the inode.
2. A directory is indeed a sort of file storing a list of names and corresponding inodes. A directory’s own name and inode are stored in its parent directory; the root directory is a special case, it is typically a fixed inode in the file system ([inode 2 in Ext4](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Special_inodes)) and is of course always named `/` (which ends up being relative to its mount point...).

Comment: The root is a different case. In this case EXT file systems add the root directory inode as part of the file system itself. I think this shall be added in order to complete the answer. BTW: I don't know the internals of other file systems, but they might be the same.