# Using octal method,how do I type the exact command I would use to make test.txt have the following permissions dr-xr-x---

Tags: permissions, chmod

Using octal method,type the exact command you would use to make test.txt have the following permissions dr-xr-x---

Comment: That trap question assumes that you cannot have a directory named `test.txt`. That assumption is false.

Comment: Linking/relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-file-types

Comment: A directory named test.txt is OK, but d for a file is not possible. read man chmod

Answer (score 0):

If `test.txt` is a text-file, you cannot do this.  If it happens be be a **directory**:

```
chmod 550 test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally I skip orders that are not questions; but in this case here is *exactly what you ordered*, using the octal method to type out to a TTY the exact command that I would use.

```
$ printf '\151\156\163\164\141\154\154\040\055\144\040\055\155\040\060\065\065\060\040\164\145\163\164\056\164\170\164\012'
```

The point where you understand this by yourself, with no further explanation, is the point where Unix shell scripting is becoming second nature.  ☺