# How to change file permission of shell files

Tags: linux, chmod

I have a directory where a lot of bash scripts or `.sh` files exist. I want to change their permissions to `770` (`rwxrwx---`) with the `chmod` command.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: This post and answer explains chmod usage and file permissions:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-file-types

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo chmod 770 /path/to/your/folder/*.sh
```

This will set the file permissions to 770 for all `.sh` files in the directory `/path/to/your/folder/`

Comment: No need for -R in this case, would only lead to unintended changes if a directory with other files was named `something.sh`.

Comment: @TamasH. Thanks, you're right. Got carried away a little by the other answer.

Answer (score -1):

Best way is using find command with the -exec option where you can use chmod.
$ find /my/bashfiles/ -type d -name *.c -exec chmod 770 {} \;
[enter link description here](https://www.poftut.com/set-permission-folders-subfolders-linux/)read below: https://www.poftut.com/set-permission-folders-subfolders-linux/

Comment: This command will find directories which end with `.c`, which is not at all what the OP asked.