# Is Linux file permission cumulative like Windows?

Tags: files

I'm pretty new to the operating systems deal and I've only learned a few basic topics such as the user and file management system in Linux. I have a question regarding the file permission in Linux. Is it cumulative just like windows? For example in Windows, if a user has read permission on a file and that user belongs to a group that has write permission on the same file, that user will have both read and write permission. Is it the same case for Linux?

Answer (score -1):

In a word, no.

This earlier question+answer explains in more depth.  [Understanding UNIX permissions and file types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-file-types)

Comment: For basic permissions yes, but there are also ACLs and in some case SELinux extensions.