# Interpretation of file permission on Linux/Unix

Tags: linux, files, permissions

I have an application trying to read files in a directory in a Linux Env. My directory permission is 'drwxrwxrwx' but the app doesn't have access to the files under this directory.
However, when I move the files to another directory with 'drwxrwxrwx.' it works properly.
I did my searches, can anyone explain what is that '.' at the end of permissions and how does it work?

Comment: Related but not a duplicate [Understanding UNIX permissions and file types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183994/100397)

Answer (score 3):

GNU `ls` uses a `.` character to indicate a file has a SELinux security context, but no other alternate access method.

To view a file's SELinux context, invoke `ls` with the `Z` option. For example:

```
# ls -alZ /etc/passwd /etc/shadow
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root system_u:object_r:passwd_file_t:s0 2490 Oct 28  2019 /etc/passwd
----------. 1 root root system_u:object_r:shadow_t:s0      1319 Aug 21 14:02 /etc/shadow
#
```

By the way, a file with any other combination of alternate access methods such as file ACLs is marked with a `+` character.