# File permissions: what is the difference between 755 and 4755

Tags: permissions

Both permission sets mean owner can read,write,execute; group and world can read,execute.

I expect 4755 to be  `r--rwxr-xr-`x, but instead it is `-rwsr-xr-x`.

What is it?

*Copying my comment to StephenKitt below*

I've been visualising the permissions as literal bits. So that 755 is `111101101`, But now we have a `100` in front of those -- so now `100111101101` which is somehow combined to put an 's' in that first field. It's not an AND because `7&4` is 4, and in fact `7` is as high we can go. So clearly my visualisation/expectation is astray.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding UNIX permissions and file types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-file-types)

Comment: @StephenKitt Not entirely. I've been visualising the permissions as literal bits. So that `755` is 111101101, But now we have a  `100` in front of those -- so now 100111101101 which is somehow combined to put an 's' in that first field. It's not an AND because 7&4 is 4, and in fact 7 is as high we can go. So clearly my visualisation/expectation is astray. Can you see where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binary visualisation is correct, but your character visualisation isn’t (and that’s fine, it’s a bit complicated).

The first three bits are mapped as character variations in each of the character triplets which follow:

- the topmost bit, setuid, is mapped to the executable location of the user permissions, as follows:

  - `-` if neither the executable bit nor the setuid bit are set;
  - `x` if only the executable bit is set;
  - `S` is only the setuid bit is set;
  - `s` if both bits are set;
- the second bit, setgid, is likewise mapped to the executable location of the group permissions, again using `-`, `x`, `S` and `s`;
- the third bit, the sticky bit, is mapped to the executable location of the “other” permissions, but using `-`, `x`, `T` and `t`.

Thus the twelve bits fit in nine characters:

```
       11          10           9
        |           |           |
 8  7   6    5  4   3    2  1   0
 r  w  x/s   r  w  x/s   r  w  x/t
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the same thing represented differently. The 4755 is permission where:
`4`: means that the binary will be executed as the owner (usually root), you can refer to man setuid command for more information
`7`: means that the file can be written to, read by and executed by the owner
`5`: that the group can read and execute
`5`: means that any user can read and execute (it should be `rx` in your example)

The rwsr means that the uid is set to the user (it can be also set to the group).

Comment: But why isn't it srwxrwx? See my comment to Stephen Kitt's comment above.

Comment: The `s` is visually laid on top of the `x` so that the symbolic permission bits can continue to fit in nine characters

Comment: I've just said is the same representation of the same.