# Setting permissions on files and folder - is folder perms inheritance always implicit?

Tags: permissions, users, group, chmod, chown

**Objective:** Creating a folder on the root, chown to group and add users to group - but users get too wide permissions!

Consider the following:

```
# as root

# we need a user group
groupadd team1

# we need a shared folder
mkdir /project1
chown root:team1 /project1
chmod 770 /project1

# we need users - and they get set pw elsewhere :)
for i in bob tina jim joy; do useradd $i; done

# we add them to the project group 'team1' that gives access to the shared folder
usermod -aG team1 [username]
```

What is puzzling is that user `jim` can create a file in `/project1` and user `joy` can open, change and save the file in vim or try to delete the file, which will be executed after confirmation that this is the intent.

**Question:** Is this to be considered correct behaviour? Shouldn't `chmod 770 /project1` be limited to permissions on the folder itself, but not as it appears: recursively to files within said folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behaviour.

770 permissions on a directory allow the directory’s owner and any member of the directory’s group to read, write and search the directory. This means that any member of the group can delete files in the directory and create new files, independently of the permissions and ownership of the files themselves. This is what you’re seeing; whatever permissions `jim` sets on a file, `joy` can delete it and replace it with another, which is what `vim` does.

There are additional permissions you can set on directories, in the standard Unix permissions model.

The first useful one here is the sticky bit, which restricts deletions: files can only be deleted by their owner, the directory’s owner, or `root`.

```
chmod g+t /project1
```

would set this up, and then `joy` wouldn’t be able to delete `jim`’s files.

The second useful permission is the `sgid` bit, which causes the directory’s group to be applied to newly-created files in the directory:

```
chmod g+s /project1
```

To combine both, run

```
chmod 3770 /project1
```

See [Understanding UNIX permissions and file types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183994/86440) for details.