# Why do I get permission denied even though I am part of the owner group?

Tags: permissions

I want to be able to write to a folder.

I already changed the `chmod 755` and the owner group, but it does not seem to work.

What other settings must be adjusted?

```
myName@homeserver /sharedfolders/media/Media % ll
total 64
drwxr-xr-x+ 308 nobody users 20480 Dec 18 18:42 Movies
drwxr-xr-x+  47 nobody users  4096 Nov  8 14:23 TvShows
myName@homeserver /sharedfolders/media/Media % id
uid=1000(myName) gid=985(users) groups=985(users),973(docker),998(wheel)
myName@homeserver /sharedfolders/media/Media % touch hello
touch: cannot touch 'hello': Permission denied
myName@homeserver /sharedfolders/media/Media % ls -ld .
drwxr-sr-x+  11 nobody users  4096 Mar 19  2020 .
```

```
% getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: nobody
# group: users
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
user:nobody:---
group::rwx
group:116:r-x
group:nobody:---
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:nobody:---
default:group::rwx
default:group:116:r-x
default:group:nobody:---
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to give yourself write permission on the directory where you’re trying to create files. Since you want to use the group permissions for this,

```
sudo chmod g+w .
```

will do this for the current directory, and then

```
touch hello
```

should work.

Your `chmod 755` command *doesn’t* set the group write permission bit; see [Understanding UNIX permissions and file types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183994/86440) for details.

Note that the `+` at the end of the permissions indicates that FACLs are set; you can check those with

```
getfacl .
```

Comment: thanks. I have been using linux for sometime but basic stuff still gets me. I admit: I am  careless

Comment: Is there anything I have to do about the FACL? I added the details in the post

Comment: The FACLs seem OK to me.