# symbolic style permissions in Linux

Tags: linux, permissions

Can someone explain to me how symbolic style permissions work in Linux? And help me set the permissions of `r--r-x-wx` in symbolic style on a file?

Thanks

Comment: Related: [Understanding UNIX permissions and file types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-file-types)

Answer (score 2):

Permissions are mapped as follows:

```
r <-> 4
w <-> 2
x <-> 1
```

So, if you want the owner to have `r`, the group to have `r+x` and others to have `w+x` (even if it sounds weird), you need to use:

```
chmod 453 file
```

If you want to use the letter format, you just use what you see on screen:

```
chmod u=r,g=rx,o=wx file
```