# why couldnt I cd /etc/group but return not a directory in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cd-command

I switch user to root used `su`. but i still couldnt `cd /etc/group` but the group folder is in my /etc folder.

```
root@Desktop:/etc# cd group
bash: cd: group: Not a directory
```

Comment: If you were on a UNIX with `NFS extended attribute` support, you could run `runat /etc/group` to get a shell with the current working directory set to `/etc/group`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/group` isn’t a folder, [it’s a file](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/group.5.html):

```
cat /etc/group
```

It’s used to define groups and their memberships (locally).

If you examine `/etc/group` with `ls -l`, you’ll get something like

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2487 Sep  4 14:04 /etc/group
```

The leading `-` means it’s a regular file; a folder (or directory) would have a leading `d`. See [Understanding UNIX permissions and file types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183994/86440) for details.