# Why am I not able to give write permission to users using chmod in linux?

Tags: linux, chmod

The current file permissions look like this:

```
$ ls -l file
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chiranjitd chiranjitd 0 Oct 30 14:52 file
```

Now I try to give write permissions using `chmod`:

```
$ chmod +x+r+w file
```

After that, the file permissions still look like this:

```
$ ls -l file
-rwxrwxr-x 1 chiranjitd chiranjitd 0 Oct 30 14:52 file
```

The write permission is not given to the others. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 23):

When you run `chmod +x+r+w file`, [all the bits are set, except those masked by your `umask`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html). Your `umask` presumably masks (at least) other users’ write bit, so the `+w` part ends up being ignored for them.

Thus for a typical `umask` of 022, any `chmod` command which doesn’t specify who the permissions should be set for ends up ignoring any specified changes to the group’s and others’ write bits.

To set all the bits, ignoring `umask`, you need to specify *who* you want to set them for:

```
chmod a+rwx file
```

or more explicitly,

```
chmod ugo+rwx file
```

(or any subset of `ugo`, as appropriate, for the user, group, and/or others).

It’s also possible to specify numeric permissions instead of symbolic permissions; see [Understanding UNIX permissions and file types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183994/86440) for details.

Note that the `umask` masking behaviour also applies when *clearing* bits, which can produce surprising results: `chmod -w file` will only clear write bits which would be set by `chmod +w file`! Continuing with a typical `umask` of 022, this means that `chmod -w` won’t touch the group’s or others’ write bits, leaving them set if they already are. (GNU `coreutils`’ `chmod` helpfully warns about this.)

Comment: oh, that last part is indeed surprising. Looks like GNU coreutils' `chmod` warns about that: `chmod 777 test.txt; chmod -w test.txt` gives `chmod: test.txt: new permissions are r-xrwxrwx, not r-xr-xr-x`

Comment: Let's not forget that once the file permission assignment is correct, the user must also have the ability to "see into" the directory (ie: `ls` returns the file listing) in addition to read/write the file itself.

Comment: @IanW that's not exactly true, they only need the right to traverse the directory (ie. `x`), not to list its content (ie. `r`).

Comment: @ginnungagap, just saying it's not just the file perms, it's also got to do with the directory settings. The respondent should add that for a complete answer, per your details, yes.

Comment: @IanW that aspect doesn’t come into play here, as indicated by the OP’s initial `ls -l` (which wouldn’t work correctly if the OP couldn’t read and traverse the current directory). I prefer to keep answers focused on the problem at hand, rather than attempting to address all possible areas of misunderstanding.

Comment: Nitpick: that initial `ls -l` tells us nothing about what _other users_ can see, since that was run by the owner.  (You're right not to clutter the answer second-guessing that part, though - that's a totally different question!)

Comment: @Toby not really a nitpick, thanks — I was reading the comments as determining whether the `chmod` would even be possible, not as being about the permissions required so that others could write to the file! But even for that, if one assumes the read permission was already effective, then everything is already OK.