# Copying a file into a directory where I am a member of the directory group

Tags: permissions, group, ownership

I am attempting to copy a file into a directory where my user account is not the directory owner but belongs to a group that is the directory group owner. These are the steps I have taken:

###### Create a group and add me to that group

```
stephen@pi:~ $ sudo groupadd test-group
stephen@pi:~ $ sudo usermod -a -G test-group stephen
stephen@pi:~ $ grep 'test-group' /etc/group
test-group:x:1002:stephen
```

###### Create a file and list permission

```
stephen@pi:~ $ touch example.txt
stephen@pi:~ $ ls -l example.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephen stephen 0 Feb  9 10:46 example.txt
```

###### Create a directory, modify the group owner to the new group and alter permission to the directory to grant write permission to the group

```
stephen@pi:~ $ sudo mkdir /var/www/testdir
stephen@pi:~ $ sudo chown :test-group /var/www/testdir/
stephen@pi:~ $ sudo chmod 664 /var/www/testdir/
stephen@pi:~ $ sudo ls -l /var/www
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root       4096 Oct 31 12:17 html
drw-rw-r-- 2 root    test-group 4096 Feb  9 10:48 testdir
```

###### Copy the newly created file into this directory

```
stephen@pi:~ $ cp example.txt /var/www/testdir/straight-copy.txt
cp: failed to access '/var/www/testdir/straight-copy.txt': Permission denied
```

To me, this should have been successful; I'm a member of the group that has ownership of this directory, and the group permission is set to rw. Ultimately, I want any files that are copied into this directory to inherit the permission of the parent directory (/var/www/testdir).

I can copy with `sudo`, but this does not inherit the owner or permission from the parent directory, nor does it retain the original ownership (probably as I'm elevated to root to copy):

###### Copy with `sudo` and list ownership/permission of file

```
stephen@pi:~ $ sudo cp example.txt /var/www/testdir/straight-copy.txt
stephen@pi:~ $ sudo ls -l /var/www/testdir/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb  9 11:06 straight-copy.txt
```

Please is someone able to explain to me what is happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you did:

```
sudo usermod -a -G test-group stephen
```

Only the group database (the contents of `/etc/group` in your case) was modified. The corresponding gid was not automagically added to the list of supplementary gids of the process running your shell (or any process that has `stephen`'s uid as their effective or real uids).

If you run `id -Gn` (which starts a new process (inheriting the uids/gids) and executes `id` in it), or `ps -o user,group,supgrp -p "$$"` (if supported by your `ps`) to list those for the shell process, you'll see `test-group` is not among the list.

You'd need to log out and log in again to start new processes with the updated list of groups (`login` (or other logging-in application) calls `initgroups()` which looks at the `passwd` and `group` database to set the list of gids of the ancestor process of your login session).

If you do `sudo -u stephen id -Gn`, you'll find that `test-group` is in there as `sudo` does also use `initgroups()` or equivalent to set the list of gids for the target user. Same with `sudo zsh -c 'USERNAME=stephen; id -Gn'`

Also, [as mentioned separately](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/689926/86440), you need *search* (`x`) permission to a directory be able to access (including create) any of its entries.

So here, without having to log out and back in, you could still do:

```
# add search permissions for `a`ll:
sudo chmod a+x /var/www/testdir

# copy as the new you:
sudo -u stephen cp example.txt /var/www/testdir/
```

You can also use `newgrp test-group` to start a new shell process with `test-group` as its real and effective gid, and it added to the list of supplementary gids.

`newgrp` will allow it since you've been granted membership of that group in the group database. No need for admin privilege in this case.

Or `sg test-group -c 'some command'` to run something other than a shell. Doing `sg test-group -c 'newgrp stephen'` would have the effect of adding only adding `test-group` to your supplementary gids while restoring your original (e)gid.

It's also possible to make a copy of a file and specify owner, group and permissions all at once with the `install` utility:

```
sudo install -o stephen -g test-group -m a=r,ug+w example.txt /var/www/testdir/
```

To copy `example.txt`, make it owned by `stephen`, with group `test-group` and `rw-rw-r--` permissions.

To copy the timestamps, ownership and permissions in addition to contents, you can also use `cp -p`. GNU `cp` also has `cp -a` to copy as much as possible of the metadata (short for `--recursive --no-dereference --preserve=all`).

Comment: Logout and login again?  That's pretty drastic, when `newgrp` is sitting right there!  I'd mention the less invasive version first.

Comment: @TobySpeight, `newgrp` doesn't go anywhere near fixing the problems. It starts a new shell with the new group as gid/egid which is not what we want here. Even with the `sg new-group -c 'newgrp original-gid'`, that still doesn't fix the group membership of all the processes have been started before the change of the account. Logging out (over every logging session) is the right way.

Comment: It doesn't look like the question requires the changed permissions for any other process.  But who knows?  Question askers can be vague (since they by definition don't fully grasp what's happening).  I certainly wouldn't like to have to restart every process I have running (including X sessions) when all I'm doing is copying a file.

Answer (score 6):

You need search permissions on the directory:

```
chmod 775 /var/www/testdir
```

If you want files created in the directory to be owned by the directory’s group, you also need sgid:

```
chmod 2775 /var/www/testdir
```

See [Understanding UNIX permissions and file types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183994/86440) for details.