# Liux Permissions

Tags: permissions

I'm currently learning Linux but I'm trying to understand the first set of permissions.

It reads Directory, read write,execute write I believe, `drwxr-xr-x`.

My question is, if that's correct, why is write there twice for the user?

Answer (score 0):

The `d` just means the file type. It is then split into 3 groups of 3, user, group and other. Refer to the following post: [unix permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-file-types)