# Why is the sticky bit mentioned twice in chmod but only once in the ls output?

Tags: permissions, chmod, sticky-bit

My task was to configure a directory so that users in a group could only delete files they own.

I used `chmod 1771 RandD`, as suggested by lab instructions, to accomplish this.

When running `ls -l`, the permissions were displayed as `drwxrwx--t`.

I understand why there is a `t` at the end of the permissions, since the last 1 in `chmod 1771 RandD` is responsible for other permissions. However, what is the point of the first 1 if `t` is not displayed in the user's permissions section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the characters in `ls -l`’s output serve multiple purposes; this is what’s happening here with the last character in the permissions. `t` means that the file has the execute bit for others set, *and* the sticky bit set.

If the sticky bit wasn’t set, you’d see `x` instead; if the execute bit wasn’t set, you’d see `T`.

In `chmod`, all four digits serve different purposes: the first sets “special” bits (including the sticky bit), the second sets owner permissions, the third sets group permissions, and the fourth sets “other” permissions.

See [Understanding UNIX permissions and file types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183994/86440) for details.