# What's the convention for "public" files?

Tags: debian, permissions, shared-folders

If you have 10k rep on AskUbuntu, you can [see this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/718908/455520), which I deleted, because I'm <s>apparently</s> wrong.

Basically, a user's question was about how to change permissions of theme files in `/usr/share/themes` so they could be opened for writing.

I answered that `sudo chmod a+rw /usr/share/themes` would do the trick, and admittedly `gksudo whateveryouwannado` might be the better option, but I probably take a lot of risks with my system that others don't with theirs (and [got yelled at by muru](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718907/change-usr-share-permissions-so-i-can-add-themes?noredirect=1#comment1061948_718908) for [it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718907/change-usr-share-permissions-so-i-can-add-themes?noredirect=1#comment1061949_718907)).

Specifics aside, due solely to the existence of `themes` in `/usr/share/`, I was convinced `/usr/share` was for stuff writable by all users, like themes, about which [I stand corrected](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRSHAREARCHITECTUREINDEPENDENTDATA).

So, where should packages / I put stuff that should be writable and readable by all users? (Pretending for a moment that security is not an issue, which it isn't for me.)

Comment: would you mind editing my answer again? it seems we were both changing it at same time, and your changes where automatically rejected.

Comment: You really don't care if any other user wants to delete all your stuff?  Why don't you just use a shared directory with the [sticky bit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79401/135943) set, so anyone can create files in there (that are viewable by others), but no one can delete or edit other people's files, only their own?

Comment: I would prefer to use a directory setuid to a group, in fact is what I do when I give vhosts access to users. I do welcome random users and or malware writing at will in directories.

Comment: @Wildcard ohh, so *that's* what the sticky bit does -- I'd never bothered to learn til now -- yes, that sounds workable.

Comment: I though you were more experienced. Then, a directory setuid to a group means the users of that group with be able to write at will there, and be able to manipulate the files created by the other members of that group. Some other user, including www-data, wont be able to write there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is, you should not create directories with write permission for *all* users. At least restrict the write access to a *group* of users.

By convention, all local modifications of a system are in `/usr/local/$dir`. In your scenario I would advise `/usr/local/share/themes`.

Do not be so quick dismissing security concerns. Take for instance, the example of a web server. Fully write-capable directories will be often be abused to upload scripts that are run with the privileges of the web server user (often `www-data`). If you are storing the themes with access to all users, they will be changed and subverted to distribute malware without any need to escalate to root.

As I commented in the original question, I manage web servers with hundreds of virtual hosts, and what we do is create a group for each virtual host, then add users to that group.

Will leave here a link about applying setuid and setgid to directories.

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html