# How to check if real/effective UID has rights to change a file or directory

Tags: linux, permissions

I can get the real and effective UIDs of the current user, so, given some file or directory, how can I use these UIDs to check the rights, `rwx`, that this specific user has for accessing/modifying the file or directory?

Comment: So, for a given file or directory, return the permissions that applies to a specific user given their UID and/or group memberships?

Comment: @Kusalananda: yes, I currently use `stat` to check owner against uid,s only; but groups also apply, and users with root-access. I am _hoping_ for some fast method to check all the possibilities.. (ps thx for edits)

Comment: See `man 1 access` for a starting point, but IIRC there are caveats when using it with effective UID/GID values. I can't test right now so not offering a proper answer.

Comment: Another thought. Can you simply use exception handling at the point you need to make a change to the file or directory?

Comment: @roaima: your reference to `man access` gave me the solution, thx. Calling `bcanR=(faccessat(0, fullpath, R_OK, AT_EACCESS)==0);` (same for W_OK & X_OK) solves my need (I think, unless there's a gotcha:)

Comment: You could just try. However this seems like you have some bad architecture in your program. Why do you now know which of the users will own each file?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to roaima's comment I came up with the following:

```
//snip...
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
...
    bool bcanR, bcanW, bcanX;
    //'fullpath' is to file or directory..
    bcanR=(faccessat(0, fullpath, R_OK, AT_EACCESS)==0);
    bcanW=(faccessat(0, fullpath, W_OK, AT_EACCESS)==0);
    bcanX=(faccessat(0, fullpath, X_OK, AT_EACCESS)==0);
...
//snip
```

which answers my need since it uses effective UID to check permissions.

Also based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358228/2141) need to keep in mind that **changing** the permissions (using `chmod`) can only be done by the owner or root.

Comment: You also asked about real IDs. So is this enough?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html `access()` use real UID and GID, which isn't the case when you try to open or execute a file. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html says `chmod()` don't use realUID

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克: I see, fixing it. thx