# How to copy a file I have permission to execute, but not permission to copy?

Tags: permissions, sudo, file-copy

I have a file in a subdirectory of /etc/ which I would like to copy, I can run this file as a regular user, however when I run

```
cp /etc/subdir/desired_file .
```

I am refused permission. However I can execute this file without superuser permissions. Is there a way for me to copy this file into another directory?

edit:
without changing file permissions

Comment: `ls -l /etc/file` gives you `-rws--x--x 1 root root` suid & user's executable bit enabled (lowercase s) - the bits `rwsr-x---x` are set.

Comment: Only `chmod` can change this. And `root` user has that permission. So normal user will not be able to do anything. read here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79395/how-does-the-sticky-bit-work/79401#79401

Comment: Do you have write permission in the target directory?

Comment: can you post the output of 'll filename' command.

Comment: You might think that you could start executing the program and then use a utility to copy the process memory to a file. But I believe that when you're executing a read-restricted binary, memory-reading utilities are blocked as well.

Answer (score 1):

`cp src dst` reads the contents of the `src`  file and writes in into the new `dst` file it has created.

So it needs read permission to the file.

On Linux at least and on some file systems such as `btrfs`, it can replace the `read()`s + `write()`s with a `ioctl (dest_fd, FICLONE, src_fd)` to do a so called *reflink copy* where the data is initially not duplicated on disk, but even then it still needs to open the source file for reading onto `src_fd`.

If it was enough to copy a file to bypass read restrictions, then the permission system would be severely broken.

Now, instead of copying a file, you could make a new link to it with a different name:

After:

```
ln from/src to/dst
```

For which you only need search access to the `from` directory and search+write access to the `to` directory, with `dst` on the same filesystem as `src`. You end up with both `src` and `dst`, but note that they are the same file linked to two different directories (or the same directory with different names).

Now, if `src` is *executable*, and is a native executable format (as opposed to a script for instance, though you can't run a script without read permission as the interpreter does need to be able to read it), that means the system is allowed to map the contents of the executable into the memory of one of *your* processes, which kind of amounts to reading it on your behalf.

The system does take care not to allow bypassing the read restriction. For instance, at least on Linux, the process won't generate a core dump when receiving signals such as SIGQUIT (as sent upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> ). It won't let you read `/proc/<pid>/maps` or `/proc/<pid>/mem` for that process:

```
$ cp /usr/bin/sleep .
$ chmod 111 sleep
$ ./sleep inf &
[1] 86474
$ cat /proc/$!/maps
cat: /proc/86474/maps: Permission denied
$ cat /proc/$!/mem
cat: /proc/86474/mem: Permission denied
```

It will also not let you attach a debugger to it, even with `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0`.

But the process itself can obviously read its own memory, so if you can convince it to dump it somewhere, you could recover *some* of the data in the file.

If the file is a dynamically linked ELF executable and it's not setuid/setgid... (secure-execution-mode not enabled), on GNU/Linux systems at least, you can convince the dynamic linker to inject arbitrary code into the executable with the `$LD_PRELOAD` mechanism, or tell it to use modified versions of the shared libraries it uses that have been hijacked to do that dumping by changing `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

For instance with:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void init(void) __attribute__((constructor));
static void init(void)
{
  FILE *maps, *dst;
  char exe[4096], path[4096];
  char *start, *end;
  off_t offset;
  int n;

  n = readlink("/proc/self/exe", exe, sizeof(exe));
  exe[n] = '\0';
  dst = fopen(getenv("DST"), "w");
  maps = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");

  while((n = fscanf(maps, "%p-%p%*s%lx%*s%*s%*[ ]%[^\n ]\n", &start, &end, &offset, path)) != EOF) {
    if (n == 4 && !strcmp(path, exe)) {
      printf("Dumping [%p - %p] from %s at offset %#lx\n", start, end, path, offset);
      fseek(dst, offset, SEEK_SET);
      fwrite(start, end - start, 1, dst);
    }
  }
  exit(0);
}
```

(error handling left as an exercise to the reader)

Compiled with:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -o hack.so that-file.c
```

Running `src` as:

```
DST=./dst LD_PRELOAD=./hack.so ./src
truncate -r src dst
```

Would have it dump the sections of the file that are mapped into memory into the `./dst` file.

If you have a readable copy of `src` and use:

```
cmp -l src-copy dst | perl -pe 's/\d+/sprintf"%#x",$&-1/e'
```

And match the output against the output of `objdump -h src-copy` on the offsets, you'll see it's not identical as some sections are missing or have been modified by the dynamic linker. In my tests, they were:

```
 20 .init_array   00000008  0000000000009bb0  0000000000009bb0  00008bb0  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 21 .fini_array   00000008  0000000000009bb8  0000000000009bb8  00008bb8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 22 .data.rel.ro  000000b8  0000000000009bc0  0000000000009bc0  00008bc0  2**5
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 23 .dynamic      000001f0  0000000000009c78  0000000000009c78  00008c78  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 24 .got          00000190  0000000000009e68  0000000000009e68  00008e68  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 26 .bss          000001b8  000000000000a080  000000000000a080  00009080  2**5
                  ALLOC
```

But the `.text` and `.rodata` sections at least are intact, which shows that it's futile to try to hide secrets in a non-readable dynamically linked ELF  executable.

Answer (score 0):

There could be two scenarios here:

1. Either you lack read permission on **desired_file**. You might be having execute permission on the file but to view or copy the file, read permission is required.
2. Or you lack write permissions on the destination directory.

Please go through https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm . It will help you know of unix permissions.

The owner can grant permissions using **chmod** command.

Comment: Yes I lack read and write permissions, however given that I am capable of executing the program, is there any way to get the data of the executable and place that somewhere else. I.e. indirectly copy the program?

Comment: You can ask the owner to grant permission or impersonate the group or owner id to modify permissions.

It is not possible to read a file's content with execute permission only.

Comment: You can run the below command to add the read permissions. But, this will require one time access to superuser --> chmod 755 /etc/subdir/desired_file

Comment: Yes I know about chmod, I should have made it clear in my question without gaining super user permissions.

Comment: If you're thinking about using ptrace() (eg: gdb, strace), forget it: if the "text" file is not readable you get  an EPERM error.