# Is it possible to read a file you only have executable permissions to on Linux through Bash?

Tags: permissions, executable, inode

I was wondering if it was possible to somehow get the contents of a file which you do not have read access to. I first attempted trying to get around the permissions using the inode number of the file, but I was unsuccessful. My teacher made a file which he said he locked up well, but that there were a few ways of getting to its contents. Getting into the file has nothing to do with our assignment, but I was curious as to how this could be done if it could be done. I did a bit of research, and the only post I found relating to this was to grab the inode number of the file, but after doing that, there was not too much more information regarding it. Any savvy bash/Linux users have a solution to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't even execute a file you don't have read permissions on, even if you have execute permissions, [unless the person who set it up tried really hard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16623/file-permission-execute-only)

Comment: @jeremysprofile The 'file' commands specifies that the file is setuid executable, regular fie, no read permission. The permissions are as follows: -rws--x---

Comment: @jeremysprofile, of course you can execute a file without read permission, provided it's a binary executable, not a script. Try something like `cp /bin/ls ./ls; chmod 111 ./ls; ./ls -l ./ls`

Comment: @ilkkachu, you're right, I should have specified. I didn't make that distinction as reading a binary executable is generally not valuable.

Comment: @jeremysprofile, reading binaries should be very useful for debugging, or disassembling the program. Having setuid binaries unreadable could be seen as a minor security advantage.

Comment: We already have a number of Q&As covering this area, including https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74527/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150972/ just for starters.

Comment: @JdeBP they were lousy 2 years ago, and they're still lousy now.

Comment: See [How to copy a file I have permission to execute, but not permission to copy?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/711936) for some approaches.

Answer (score 1):

NO.  Unlike executable binary output, the binary loader is a special beast with privs to read files and set them into execution.  Thus for binary files EXECUTABLE access is sufficient to get the program read and executed.

However, a shell is only an interpreter and does not have such special abilities, and as a typical progam without any special abilities, must read a file.  Thus READ access is required for a file to be "input" to a shell command processor.

Comment: When I run ls -l <file> the permissions come back as: -rws--x---.

Comment: @user3657449 It is possible to execute a file to which you don't have read permissions provided that it's not a script or otherwise interactive. That file has `setuid` which means that it will run with the permissions of the owner.

Comment: @NasirRiley Is there a way to piggyback on this permission to output all commands run in the script to the standard output?

Comment: @user3657449 If it's a binary then you can use `strace` to see the system calls. If it's a script then it won't be possible because it won't run due to your inability to read the file.

Comment: @user357449 - if it is a script, all you would have to do is `cat scriptname` since all shell scripts have to have READ access.

Comment: @mdpc If I try anything like cat, less, head, tail, etc. I get permission denied.

Comment: @NasirRiley Is there any way to use strace to print out the exact lines used in the file? Or just the system calls it reports?

Comment: @user3657449 It is just the system calls. Like I said, you can't read the lines within because you don't have read access to it.

Comment: @mdpc The script only has to have read access for the user who is executing it. If someone without read access tries to use `cat`, `less`, or any other command that is used to read the file it then they'll get `permission denied`.

Comment: No, the binary loader / dynamic linker / ELF interpreter (`ld.so`) doesn't have any extra privileges. It's not a setuid, setgid or setcap executable; the ELF interpreter is able to "read" a non-readable binary executable because the kernel loads the binary in the virtual memory of the process *before* loading and running the interpreter. The interpreter doesn't open the file via the file system and doesn't need to bypass any permission.