# How to set permissions for future files?

Tags: permissions, acl

I freely admit this is homework:

> Imagine you and your friend host an IT faculty in your former school. The list of attendees is in the attached text file. You need to manage permissions for directories `documents`, `tasks` and `solutions`. Write a script that creates accounts for all attendees and sets permissions in such a way that:
>
> - Every attendee has the right to read files that will be created in the directory `documents`, while your friend has the right to read and modify files from this directory, but can't add or remove anything;
> - Every attendee has the right to read files that will appear in the directory `tasks`, while your friend has all rights to this directory;
> - Every attendee has the right to place their solutions in the directory `solutions/<ID of attendee>-<ID of task>`;
> - Your friend has all rights to the `solutions` directory tree, while the attendees can't see the solutions of their peers.

This is homework from basic file permissions (`chmod`, `umask`) and ACLs (`setfacl`)

Now this is what perplexes me:

We have to set fine-grained permissions for files that are not yet present but will be created in the future?!?!

To my understanding:

- `umask` allows us to set default permissions for newly created files; but these are only the basic owner-group-others permissions, so I can't really differentiate my friend's permissions with attendees' permissions with attendees' peers' permissions;
- `setfacl` ONLY allows me to set permissions for files that already exists or I create, but NOT files that will be created in the future!

So I'm ignorant on how to do this homework. Can someone show me the right track?

Comment: Not true. ACLs do handle future files. It's the sticky bit that's a "bit" difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Some pointers to get you into right direction:

- ACL [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man5/acl.5.html#object%20creation%20and%20default%20acls) section says about default ACLs:

  > The access ACL of a file object is initialized when the object is created with any of the **creat()**, **mkdir()**, **mknod()**, **mkfifo()**, or **open()** functions. If a default ACL is associated with a directory, the *mode* parameter to the functions creating file objects and the default ACL of the directory are used to determine the ACL of the new object:
  >
  > 1. The new object inherits the default ACL of the containing directory as its access ACL.
  > 2. The access ACL entries corresponding to the file permission bits are modified so that they contain no permissions that are not contained in the permissions specified by the mode parameter.
- Using sticky bit on directories you can change the owner/group of the new files created in the directory. Files created in directory will have the owner/group of the sticky directory instead of the default group. For more details, see question: [How does the sticky bit work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79395/how-does-the-sticky-bit-work)