# One of the files my application creates "is not a file"

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, arm

I've been struggling for several days because I run an application that actually runs more application and these generate outputs. The case is that one of these outputs is generated with the following permissions:

```
?-wxr-s--- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1318 Aug 28 12:55 output_app.err
```

Then you could think to do something like, `sudo vim output_app.err` but reports the following `output_app.err is not a file`. This output is generated in a *bash* script, exactly the command is executed using eval and the output is redirected. I thought that this error could be related with the filesystem corruption, I am running Ubuntu in a arm-32bit processor living in a SD card.

I runned dmesg and I saw that error after the application was executed:

```
[ 1203.425248] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000104
[ 1203.432000] pgd = d6748000
[ 1203.433343] [00000104] *pgd=00000000
Internal error: Oops - BUG: 805 [#8] PREEMPT SMP ARM
```

Any ideas of why this would happend? Thank you.

Comment: Try `chmod u+r output_app.err`. The attributes are a little [s](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79395/66388)trange... you may need to put `sudo` before (you are not mr ubuntu). Check even if `lsof` say something on that file...

Comment: You've got a kernel bug, causing corruption in (at least) the filesystem. What kernel are you running (`uname -a`) and is there a later version to which you can upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if the file has no known type, so there is most likely a defective filesystem.

I recommend you to run a filesystem check.

If this is not possible, try to remove the file and to re-create it.

Comment: Yes, I already did a fsck.my_filesystem. But this is not going to solve my error at all. Thank you

Comment: Do you have a `clri` command that is useful for this filesystem?