# How to remove directory flags on linux?

Tags: acl

I have a folder called "post", when I write `getfacl post` I get these results:

```
# file: post
# owner: www-data
# group: ftpgroup
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

As you can see there is a `-s-` flag, and the default permission for group is rwx, so new files should be 775.

If I write `ls -lha` I got these perms:

```
drwxrwsr-x+ 22 www-data ftpgroup 4.0K Dec  3 20:56 post
```

as you can see, another `s` appears, when I create a new folder (using a different user in the same group) perms goes 755 instead of 775.

I think this flag is doing something wrong, How to remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `s` flag located on the group octet is called the SET-GID bit. Any new files created in a directory with the SET-GID bit set will be owned by the group who owns the parent directory. Also, any new sub-directories will inherit the SET-GID bit.

To add the SET-GID bit you can use:

`chmod g+s directory`

To remove the SET-GID bit you can use:

`chmod g-s directory`

---

In regard to getting 755 instead of 775 permissions, check the `umask` of the system. The `umask` you are looking for is `002`.

You can make the umask permanent for the user by placing `umask 002` in `${HOME}/.bashrc` or `${HOME}/.profile`, or make it the system default by placing it in `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/profile`.

Comment: It is odd that the accepted answer offers no explanation of why the created directory has `r-x` rather than `rwx` group access, seemingly the core of the question.  melds's answer does.

Comment: @JdeBP: To be honest, I read right over that when I answered. See my latest edit. I go into more detail on the umask portion. I appreciate you pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

The 's' flag on a folder is the SETGID flag and is like the sticky bit ([How does the sticky bit work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79395/how-does-the-sticky-bit-work)) and changes how ownership and permissions word in the folder (SETGID forces file created in the folder to have the same group membership).

You can remove it by doing a `chmod 0775` or `chmod g-s` to the parent directory.

You also may want to look at the other user's `umask` setting if other flags aren't being set the way you'd want.

Comment: The sticky bit is represented by a `t`. `s` is the set user or group ID bit.

Comment: @Peschke You're right. I tend to use the wrong term for persistent flags like this. I'll update my answer.