# Difference between owner and group

Tags: permissions, security, directory, group

Can we consider the owner as a group that has exactly 1 member? Does the owner have any special abilities apart from the given permissions?

I want to have two equal users with the same permissions in directories. These two users (`user1`, `user2`) will have `rwx`. I need another user (`user3`) who has `rx` or `wx` depending on the dir.

Can I `chown` the dirs to `user3` and assign `user1`, `user2` to the same group?

- `owner` = `user3` (`rx` || `rw` depending on the dir)
- `group` = `user1`, `user2` (`rwx` on all dirs)

`user1` and `user2` are hard linked to `user3` `/home` dir. (I don't know if this is the best practice for a shared dir)

I want to avoid `ACL` if possible.

edit: `user1` and `user2` are needed so their individual actions in the system can be traced.

Answer (score 3):

> Can we consider the owner as a group that only has exactly 1 member? Does the owner have any special abilities apart from the given permissions?

Not really. The owner owns the file and can change its metadata. For example, the commands `chown`, `chgrp`, `chmod` only work for the owner of a file/directory (or for `root`).

For non-ACL permissions, the owner, group, and other are exclusive groups - an account cannot be in more than one of them.

With this information you should be able to see that restricting the access permissions of a directory owner makes little sense, because as the owner they can assign any permission they choose. Therefore in your example you cannot have `user3` as the owner.

Me, I'd probably own the directory as `root`. I'd have `user1` and `user2` in a group as you suggest. And `user3` I'd leave out entirely so they they were considered as "other".

If you had yet other accounts on the system that should not be able to access these directories like `user3`, I'd create another group containing all the permitted users and use a directory with that group permission to host the target directory:

```
holding_dir: owner:root=rwx, group:big_group(users 1,2,3):rx, other:-
  |
  +-- target1: owner:root=rwx, group:small_group(users 2,3):rwx, other:rx
  +-- target2: owner:root=rwx, group:small_group(users 2,3):rwx, other:wx
```

Comment: > For example, the commands chown, chgrp, chmod only work for the owner of a file/directory (or for root)

Thanks. I didn't take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

Well one case would be if the sticky bit ( [restricted deletion flag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79401/123460) `t`) is set on a directory, like in the case of `/tmp`.

Here only the **owner** of a file may delete it (or the **owner** of the directory) - no matter the group permissions.

---

Now for your case:

The owner may as well run `chmod u+w` as much as he likes, so the approach will fail.

---

Simple and possible solution:
Why not make `user1` and `user2` have the same UID and hand the ownership to said UID? Would that clash with other restrictions on your system?